# Partial replace/update on a data frame

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(47)
df <- data.frame(V1 = sample(letters[1:5], size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = 101:110)

partial_key <- data.frame(V1 = letters[1:3], V2 = 1:3)

> df
   V1  V2
1   e 101
2   b 102
3   d 103
4   e 104
5   c 105
6   d 106
7   b 107
8   c 108
9   c 109
10  e 110


> partial_key
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
```

I'd like to replace the values of `V2` in `df` with the corresponding values from `partial_key` that match in the `V1` columns. The non-matches should remain as is.

With a complete key, I'd use `match`, which replaces the correct values, but replaces the non-matches with `NA`.

```
df[, "V2"] <- partial_key[match(df$V1, partial_key$V1), "V2"]
## Replaces too much
```

I can hack together a solution with `%in%`, but is there a better way? Something more intuitive, with less typing?

```
df[df$V1 %in% partial_key$V1, "V2"] <-
partial_key[match(df$V1[df$V1 %in% partial_key$V1], partial_key$V1), "V2"]
## Works, but is there a better way?
> df
   V1  V2
1   e 101
2   b   2
3   d 103
4   e 104
5   c   3
6   d 106
7   b   2
8   c   3
9   c   3
10  e 110
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `%in%` is unnecessary since the output of `match` already contains that info. So you can do something like this:

```
replacement <- partial_key$V2[match(df$V1, partial_key$V1)]
df$V2 <- ifelse(is.na(replacement), df$V2, replacement)
```

Sometimes I wish R had a base `if.na` function similar to Excel's `IFERROR`. I have it in my Rprofile:

```
if.na <- function(value, value.if.na) ifelse(is.na(value), value.if.na, value)
df$V2 <- if.na(replacement, df$V2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge and then do the desired rearrnagements

```
> mdf <- merge(df, partial_key, by="V1", all.x=TRUE)
> mdf$V2.x[!is.na(mdf$V2.y)] <- mdf$V2.y[!is.na(mdf$V2.y)]
> mdf
   V1 V2.x V2.y
1   b    2    2
2   b    2    2
3   c    3    3
4   c    3    3
5   c    3    3
6   d  106   NA
7   d  103   NA
8   e  101   NA
9   e  104   NA
10  e  110   NA
> mdf[-3]
   V1 V2.x
1   b    2
2   b    2
3   c    3
4   c    3
5   c    3
6   d  106
7   d  103
8   e  101
9   e  104
10  e  110
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
comb <- rbind(df, partial_key)
df$V2 <- head(ave(comb$V2, comb$V1,
                  FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)), -nrow(partial_key))
```